# How to convert a string to decimal in a LINQ query

Tags: linq

I have the following Linq statement:

```
var total = (from a in mobileChunk.Data select a.callCost).Sum();
```

`callCost` is a string. I need to convert it to a decimal. How is this done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i would do something like this....

```
public static class Extenders
{
    public static decimal ToDecimal(this string str)
    {
        // you can throw an exception or return a default value here
        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ) 
          return someDefaultValue;

        decimal d ;

        // you could throw an exception or return a default value on failure
        if ( !decimal.TryParse(str, out d ) ) 
           return someDefaultValue; 

        return d;
    }
}
```

now, in your linq.....

```
var total = = (from a in mobileChunk.Data select a.callCost.ToDecimal()).Sum();
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution because it can accommodate empty strings and null strings.

Comment: @JL which is why I did it this way :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
var total = (from a in mobileChunk.Data select decimal.Parse(a.callCost)).Sum();
```